# JsReport: Formatting date

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsreport

I am getting my date from the database in RFC 3339 format:

```
2020-08-11T00:00:00.000Z
```

I want the date in the PDF to show as:

```
2020-08-11
```

But the date shows as:

```
Tue Aug 11 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

Please help achieve my desired formatting.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to print a date in javascript.

The main issue is that date is treated as a locale object, meaning that its formatting will change based on the browser's locale. In order to obtain your formatting you can do:

```js
var d = new Date("2020-08-11T00:00:00.000Z");

console.log(d.getFullYear() + "-" +  (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +  d.getDate());
```